# Pagination in wordpress show the same post

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a realy big problem with pagination. When i click next post - wordpress show me the same 9 post. What is bad with this? This is meybe on $row array? I need custome post view, and pagination.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 9,
      'paged' => $paged
    );
    $query = new WP_Query ( array( $args )  );  

        $row = array(6, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6);
        $i = 0;
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $the_query->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
        ?>

        <div class="col-md-<?php echo $row[$i] ?> col-xs-6">
            <div class="blog-item scrollpoint sp-effect2">
                <div class="cover" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumbnail[0] ?>')">
                    <div class="mask">
                        <div class="post">
                            <span class="kategoria"></span>
                            <div class="tresc">
                                <h1> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                                <div class="wypis"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

     <?php 
            $i++;
            endwhile; ?> 

            <!-- pagination -->
           <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer posts') ?>
            <?php next_posts_link('Older posts &raquo;') ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
            <?php else : ?>

     <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [previous_posts_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) and [next_posts_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) are designed to show the next or former post from the currently displayed post. You're displaying a loop.

If, as this seems, you are just making a blog index page and requesting regular posts, then you just need to make links that append /{paged}/ to the end, like so:

```
<a href="/blogpage/<?php echo $paged + 1; ?>/">Next</a>
<?php if($paged > 1): ?>
<a href="/blogpage/<?php echo $paged - 1; ?>/">Previous</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Where blogpage is the page this is supposed to appear (if the home, just do / )

If you're doing something more complicated, like a custom post type with a custom permalink structure, look into [query_vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) and the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).