# WordPress 6 function show_posts shows the same content for each

Tags: wordpress

it loops correctly 10 times but with wrong content. it alloys using the content with id 11

#### show_posts with 10 posts (thats correct) but always first content

my `function show_posts` in `Theme.php` :

```php
    public function show_posts() { # show_posts220914() { 
            $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => 200
        );
        $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
        if( ! empty( $my_posts ) ){
            foreach ( $my_posts as $post ){
                get_template_part( 'content','content');
            }
        }
    }
```

so result in http://localhost/wordpress/ is

```html
<li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li><li>11</li>
```

#### show_posts with correct constant but to less posts:

in this next try i have correct constant but to less posts:

```php
    public function  show_posts(){
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, ['posts_per_page' => 200 ] ); # has no effect here 
        query_posts( $args ); # has no effect here 
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $post= the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content','content');
            endwhile;
        endif;
    }
```

so result in http://localhost/wordpress/ is

```html
<li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li></li>
```

my `content.php`:

```php
<li>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</li>
```

my `home.php`:

```php
<ol>
    <?php 
    do_action( 'home_content' ); 
    ?>
</ol>
```

i call it with http://localhost/wordpress/.
i don't use any pages. means http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page tells me `No pages found`.

i found inspiration here:

- [get_template_part/#parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/#parameters)
- [show-the-same-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270988/pagination-in-wordpress-show-the-same-post)
- [query_posts('posts_per_page=20')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3875960/2891692)

i using `WordPress 6.0.2`

any idea?

Comment: Off course it does because you are calling the function that pulls the value of the `global $post` object, so depending on what page you are viewing, it will always show the title of that page, dont use `get_template_part` but output the title directly inside your function instead

Comment: i don't view any page and i don't have any page. i open open/read http://localhost/wordpress/ that shows my all posts (if i open a other theme)
means http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page tells me `No pages found.`

Comment: make it worst, you are calling `the_title` in an archive page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get this correct output

```html
<li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li>
```

if i use this:

`Theme.php` :

```php
    public function show_posts_so() { 
        $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1));
        if ( count($posts)>0 ) :
            foreach($posts as $this_special_post){
                get_template_part( 'content','content', $this_special_post);   
            }
        endif;
    }
```

`content.php` :

```php
<li><?php echo $args->ID ?></li>
```

`functions.php` :

```php
add_action( 'home_content', [$theme ,'show_posts_so']);
```

`home.php` :

```php
    <?php   do_action( 'home_content' );    ?>
```

it helps me reading this: [What is the real purpose of magic method __set_state in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441958/what-is-the-real-purpose-of-magic-method-set-state-in-php)
and the use of the [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.var-export.php) command sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Your second WordPress loop looks like it could almost work ... I'm not sure what `$wp_query->query_vars` could contain that you are merging with your `post_per_page` constraint.

Try this, more standard loop ([and/or read about the loop on WordPress' Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)):

```
function show_post(){
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();         
 
        get_template_part( 'content','content');   

    endwhile;
endif;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: loops in my question are inside the `function show_post`  inside the `Theme.php` How could i use your code inside `Theme.php` (if possible) ?

Comment: Updated to illustrate context. The loop that I provided is a standard implementation and _should_ work in your case. But - I do not know what theme you are using, or what your theme does before or after the `show_post()` function.

Comment: i have no result with your solution. need try some modification

Comment: What happens if you replace `get_template_part();` with `var_dump(get_the_ID());` ?

Comment: no result if i use `var_dump(get_the_ID());` or `var_export(get_the_ID());`

Comment: i added some `        echo '###' . __LINE__ . '-' . __LINE__ . '-' . __LINE__ . '-' . __LINE__. '###' ;`
and found out it not goes into `have_post` so the query is empty

Comment: This may turn into a dead end without more context on your theme. But, maybe you're already inside a loop when `show_posts()` is called. What if you add `wp_reset_postdata();` before the `$args` array in the `show_posts()` function? 

Do you know where `show_posts()` is called to your theme? There should be `add_action( '_somehook_', 'show_posts', _somenumber_);` that activates the function.

Comment: still empty. yes i now where i use `add_action`. i comment out tries i not yet testing. so it looks at moment like so: ```// add_action( 'home_content', [$theme ,'show_posts']);
// add_action( 'home_content', [$theme ,'show_posts220914']);
// add_action( 'home_content', [$theme ,'show_posts_NO']);
add_action( 'home_content', [$theme ,'show_posts_so']);
```
means i not rename the function names while i testing and switch between the different tries.

Comment: I see. So - your theme is doing something a little abnormal (not wrong, though) by passing the `$theme` variable as well as the function callback. If you try `add_action('wp_head', 'show_posts');`, do you see output at the top of every page?

Comment: `add_action('wp_head', 'show_posts_SomeVersion');` shows nothing

Comment: Gee-whiz. At this stage, I would personally be trying to use `var_dump('What the heck? Show this message!');` in many locations within the function to try to figure out if any output is possible. You're probably going to have to share your theme name in your original post, perhaps reach out to the theme authors and/or review the theme documentation.

Comment: this is visible before the loop. i prefer    `     echo '###' . __LINE__ '-' . __LINE__ '-' . __LINE__ '-' . __LINE__ '###' ;`  so the query is empty